# Error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'Special[]'

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I am writing an app in Angular. I am using json file, by getting data from it in the ts file:

```
import * as data from '../../special.json';
export class SpecialComponent {
  specials = (data as any).default;
}
```

And everything is fine. But when I want to add type instead of any:

```
import * as data from '../../special.json';
export class SpecialComponent {
  specials = (data as Special[]).default;
}
```

I get an error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'Special[]'.
```

This is my interface on service:

```
export interface Special {
  category: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  type?: string;
  imageUrl?: string;
}
```

This is my json file:

```
[
    {
        "category": "xxx",
        "name": "xxx",
        "description": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx",
        "imageUrl": [
            "assets/img/img.jpg",
            "assets/img/img1.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Try reading the json file using `HttpClient` rather than importing it?

Comment: You're trying to access property `default` of an array, try to log content of `data` first.

Comment: How to log content of data?

Comment: @Weronika: Try `console.log(data)` to log it and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct, because there is no `default` on `Special[]`.

One easy way to do what you are trying to do is:

Put  `resolveJsonModule` and `esModuleInterop` in `tsconfig.json` file of project.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  ....
}
```

and then import:

```
import {default as data} from '../../special.json';
export class SpecialComponent {
  specials = data as Special[];
}
```